# Django call https : [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed

Tags: python, django, ssl

I have to call a api(`requests.post(https://192.168.16.10:8443/api/data,json=data)`)  in my django .
It's `https` ,so I install   `django-sslserver`

to run django with https

But I got error  `[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed`

What else should I set??

I try to call `https://192.168.16.10:8443/api/data`  directly by `Postman` , It works well.
It's the django  problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a self-signed certificate you can skip certificate verification:

```
requests.post("https://192.168.16.10:8443/api/data", verify=False)
```

See [`requests` documentation on SSL verification](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification) for details.

**Warning:** This will reduce the security of SSL as @KlausD pointed out and should be used as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this command to skip this step

```
pip install djangorestframework --trusted-host=pypi.python.org --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org
```